# /temp/ directory disappears cpanel

Tags: security

I have a dedicated server running Linux/Apache with cPanel. On one of my website's users are able to register and upload images.

However, over the last few days, i have received complaints that users cannot upload any media. When I check the /images/ directory I see that the /temp/ folder is missing.

So I re-created it and set the permissions to 0777.

Once that is completed all works fine. But I cannot understand why the directory is being removed.  No one else has access to the site and I do not see anything in my error logs that show anything unusual.

Any ideas why this may happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your PHP Script has code to unlink(dir) or Something

and Check cron list whether you have added any CRON to remove the TMP folder.

- for Write permission 755 is enough If you are using Fcgi php handler, cgi, dso. Have a try 755 permission with one of the listed Handlers.